# Array multidimensional y explode, ¿cómo iterar en bucle while?

Tags: php, array

Si hago esto :

```
$xxx = explode (" ", (string) $valium);
```

`explode` devuelve una `array`, guardado en `$xxx` a partir de un `string` dividido por espacios. Pero no sé cómo iterar correctamente con ello. Muestro aquí mi intento que no me da error pero no me ofrece ningun resultado:

```
$xxx= array();
$MDKey = array();
$jk = 0;

/*el valor de count($valium)-1 es 6*/
while ($jk <= (count($valium) - 1)) {   /*valium es un array con 7 strings, cada uno de ellos debe convertirse en un array (de ahi el explode)*/

    $xxx = explode (" ", (string) $valium[$jk]);
    $MDKey = $MDKey[$jk][$xxx];
    $jk++;

}

print_r($MDKey[1][1]);   /* sin resultado por pantalla...*/

var_dump($MDKey[1][1]);
```

¿Un `array` multidimensional se puede usar así?

¿Cuál es la manera "Normal" de realizar esto? Soy novato en `php` y llega un punto que se me satura la mente.

Comment: Una recomendación: simplifica la condición del `if`. Con algo como `while($jk < count($valium)){` obtendrías el mismo resultado y sería más fácil de leer y más eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando manejes arrays con php te recomiendo que uses: `var_dump($xxx);` sirve para saber que contiene el arreglo.

Por lo que he entendido tu variable `$valium` debería contener algo como:

`$valium = "stack over flow";`

Así que la función `count($valium)` siempre te va a devolver 1. Count sirve para contar elementos de un array [Count()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php).

La variable $MDKey no tiene ningún sentido, no le das nunca ningún valor.

Explode es mas sencillo:

```
$valium = "stack over flow";
$xxx = explode (" ",$valium);

for($i=0; $i < count($xxx); $i++) {
    echo "Numero $i:".$xxx[$i]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: La variable `$valium` es un array de cadenas según el comentario del código...

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un array con distintas cadenas, lo más sencillo es usar un `foreach` para iterar sobre los diferentes elementos. En cada iteración, haces el `explode` e iteras sobre el array resultante. De esta forma acabarás iterando las palabras contenidas en los elementos de `$valium`:

```
foreach ($valium as $cadena) {
    $palabras = explode(' ', $cadena);
    foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        echo $palabra;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### El error:

```
$MDKey = $MDKey[$jk][$xxx];
```

Estas asignando al `array $MDKey` el valor del `array $MDKey` en la dimensión `[$jk][$xxx]`, es decir, `null`.

### Preguntas y respuestas

> un array multidimensional se puede usar así?

No, en tu caso, para crear un `array` multidimensional deberías hacerlo así:

```
$MDKey[$jk] = $xxx;
// Asignamos al $MDKey en la posición $jk el array $xxx
```

> Cual es la manera "Normal" de realizar esto?

¿Normal? Para iterar un `array`, yo usaría un `foreach` en lugar de un `while`.

### Solución:

Podrías hacerlo así:

```
/*valium es un array con 7 strings, cada uno de ellos debe convertirse en un array (de ahi el explode)*/
$MDKey = array();

foreach ($valium as $string) {
  $MDKey[] = explode (" ", (string) $string);
}

print_r($MDKey[1][1]);
var_dump($MDKey[1][1]);
```